# What actions are performed by Install OS X Mountain Lion.app that are not performed by InstallESD.dmg without the app?

Tags: macos, install, hacking

## Recommended

Apple provides and recommends use of **Install OS X Mountain Lion**.app

- that is, "the app" – in its entirety.

For Build 12A269 for OS X 10.8, the version of the app is 1.3.12 (351).

## Known

Ignoring parts of the app – with `InstallESD.dmg` alone:

- installation *may* succeed.

(The same is true [for Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/47250/8546) when parts of Install Mac OS X *Lion*.app are **not** used for installation.)

## Unknown for Mountain Lion

The full list of:

- things that do not occur, things that may not succeed, when installation is attempted or performed with **something other than the app**.

My initial plan is to accept an answer that provides either:

- the fullest list; or
- the best set of evidence for a partial list.

### Starting points

[com.apple.Boot.plist(5) OS X Manual Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/com.apple.Boot.plist.5.html) – page dated March 17, 2011 for 10.7.4, the same date appears on the page within 10.8.

For Mountain Lion on some types of hardware, there may be a unique distribution (ESD).

Food for thought, just part of the Lion experience: [June 2012 discussion](http://afp548.com/forums/topic/instadmg-june-2012-macbook-pros/) of [Downloading Hardware Specific Lion Installers](http://afp548.com/article.php?story=getting-lion-installers) ([cache](http://www.diigo.com/cached?url=http://www.afp548.com/article.php?story=getting-lion-installers))([copy](http://nellen.it/blog/2012/01/downloading-hardware-specific-lion-installers/)).

Comment: I considered [Ask Different posts about `InstallESD`](http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=InstallESD) before adding this question. Is this question answered elsewhere in Stack Exchange?

Comment: … now checking the broader range of posts [about `InstallESD.dmg`](http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=InstallESD.dmg) …

Answer (score 2):

My working theory is that there are no meaningful differences in actions performed under the app as opposed to the DMG.

One could argue at a low level that the difference is that invoking the `Install OS X Mountain Lion.app` bundle loads app and UI frameworks that simply mounting a DMG does not, but that's not exactly the intent of your question I'm sure.

Any meaningful installer-level actions should be identical in either medium, since the majority of the resources are in the DMG, and the DMG is in the app. The app must mount the disk image in order to get at the necessary assets.

Comment: Thanks for this first answer … maybe worth us giving additional thought to mount point arrangements etc.. I'll add something to the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Son of InstallLion.pkg « Managing OS X](http://managingosx.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/son-of-installlion-pkg/) (2012-07-25) reminded of the Munki project.

## Actions described in the wiki for Munki

From the 2012-07-26 edition of http://code.google.com/p/munki/wiki/InstallingOSX:

> The postflight script performs the actions that the GUI
>   "Install Mac OS X Lion" or "Install OS X Mountain Lion" application
>   does when you choose to install OS X.
>
> Those actions are:
>
> 1. Create a `Mac OS X Install Data` directory at the root of the target
>      volume.
> 2. Mount the `InstallESD.dmg` disk image.
> 3. Copy the `kernelcache` and `boot.efi` files from the disk image to the `Mac OS X Install Data` directory. (The `kernelcache` is copied to
>      the Recovery HD helper partition if the target volume is encrypted
>      with FileVault 2.)
> 4. Unmount (eject) the `InstallESD.dmg` disk image.
> 5. If the `InstallLion.pkg` is on the same volume as the target volume, create a hard link to the `InstallESD.dmg` disk image in
>      `Mac OS X Install Data`, otherwise copy the `InstallESD.dmg` disk
>      image to that directory.
> 6. Create a `com.apple.Boot.plist` file in the `Mac OS X Install Data` directory which tells the kernel how to mount
>      the disk image to use for booting. (This file is instead created on
>      the the Recovery HD helper partition if the target volume is encrypted
>      with FileVault 2.)
> 7. Create a `minstallconfig.xml` file, which tells the OS X Installer what to install and to which volume to install it. It also provides a
>      path to a `MacOSXInstaller.choiceChanges` file if one has been
>      included in the package.
> 8. Create an `index.sproduct` file and an `OSInstallAttr.plist` in the `Mac OS X Install Data` directory. These are also used by the OS X
>      Installer.
> 9. Set a variable in nvram that the OS X Installer uses to find the product install info after reboot.
> 10. Use the `bless` command to cause the Mac to boot from the kernel files copied to the `Mac OS X Install Data` directory.

### Generalising for Mountain Lion, without Munki

For Ask Different, this answer requires more work.

Not definite at the moment, I assume that `InstallLion.pkg` is associated with a **postflight script of Munki** (not normally associated with Install OS X Mountain Lion.app).

Definite variations to what's quoted above:

- not `Mac OS X Install Data`; the name of the directory is `OS X Install Data`
- not `Recovery HD`; the name of the partition is `Boot OS X`.

---

In the wiki for Simian (related to Munki): [no mention of InstallESD](http://code.google.com/p/simian/w/list?can=1&q=InstallESD).

Answer (score -2):

There is no difference whatsoever. The app is just there to create an Installer image on your disk. It restores InstallESD.dmg to the target partition and moves the data to a temporary folder. Then it asks you to reboot, and the installer continues by booting from the target partition.

Comment: Potentially misleading – to the best of my knowledge the app, running, does **not** add any partition. Partitioning may occur later in the routine (when something other than the app is running).

Comment: I am sorry. I checked again, and I see it restores InstallESD.dmg to the Target Volume without erasing it. I was probably thinking about the Recovery HD when writing this answer.